# Vim + zshell, "zsh suspended" after running a Vim external command

Tags: vim, zsh

Vim newbie here (has worked with zsh for a few months now). I think I install too many dotfiles or have a wrong configuration because whenever I attempt an external command (even thing such as `:!rm TEST`, Vim exits with a message `zsh: suspended (tty output)  vim .`. How do I fix this?

The dotfiles: https://github.com/daryllxd/dotfiles. (I got them from someone else).

Comment: Did you try to perform a bisection? Did you try changing the value of the `shell` option?

Answer (score 0):

Try to comment this out:

```
set shellcmdflag=-ci
```

If this doesn't work for you look at the following.

From the manual:

```
Commands  are  first  read from /etc/zshenv; this cannot be overridden.

[...]

Commands are then read from $ZDOTDIR/.zshenv. If the shell is a
login shell, commands are read from /etc/zprofile and then 
$ZDOTDIR/.zprofile. Then, if the shell is interactive, 
commands are read from /etc/zshrc and then $ZDOTDIR/.zshrc. Finally,
if the shell is a login shell, /etc/zlogin and $ZDOTDIR/.zlogin are
read.
```

From what I understand,

set shell=zsh\ -i

should work.

Answer (score 0):

if u want back to the vim by suspended,u could use `fg`,just like this:

> fg %vim\ [u viming file]

this title maybe help u:http://ytliu.info/blog/2013/09/28/ttyde-na-xie-shi-er/